# AG Grid React: How to get the state of rows after changing the order?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

After implementing the `drag and drop` feature on `AG Grid` table, I'm looking for a way to get the current state with the updated `order/index` of rows. 
 My goal is to persist the table data after changing the order, but can't find the respective state of the current order.
I'd appreciate any help or any idea. 
[Sandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/aggridgetstate-r63uoy?file=/src/App.js) and example code below

```
import React from "react";
import { AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react";
import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css";
function App() {
  const [gridApi, setGridApi] = React.useState(null);
  const [gridColumnApi, setGridColumnApi] = React.useState(null);

  const onGridReady = (params) => {
    setGridApi(params.api);
    setGridColumnApi(params.columnApi);
  };

  const defaultColDef = {
    flex: 1,
    editable: true
  };

  const columnDefs = [
    {
      headerName: "Name",
      field: "name",
      rowDrag: true
    },
    { headerName: "stop", field: "stop" },
    {
      headerName: "duration",
      field: "duration"
    }
  ];

  const rowData = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        name: "John",
        stop: 10,
        duration: 5
      },
      {
        name: "David",
        stop: 15,
        duration: 8
      },
      {
        name: "Dan",
        stop: 20,
        duration: 6
      }
    ],
    []
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 align="center">React-App</h1>
      <div>
        <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{ height: "700px" }}>
          <AgGridReact
            columnDefs={columnDefs}
            rowData={rowData}
            defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
            onGridReady={onGridReady}
            rowDragManaged={true}
          ></AgGridReact>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the order of the rows inside the grid by iterating over them using the Grid API method `forEachNode`:

[API for Row Nodes](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-api/#reference-rowNodes)

```
const rows = [];
gridApi.forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort((node) => rows.push(node.data));
console.log(rows);
```

See this implemented in the [following sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/aggridgetstate-forked-zl5r1j?file=/src/App.js:1119-1245).

Comment: I've not tried this personally, but it seems there's a potential to introduce bugs or unnecessary re-renders. If you pull this info out of the component and save it to your parent component state, then your parent component is going to re-render, and cause AgGridReact to re-render. I'm not sure what the AgGridReact component will do when it is passed the same data while also being in `rowDragManaged` mode. It might be fine, but worth keeping a close eye on.

Answer (score 0):

You're currently using managed dragging by passing `rowManagedDragging={true}`, which means the AgGridReact component is managing the row order state.

If you want to maintain row order state outside the component, you need to use [Unmanaged Dragging](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/row-dragging/#unmanaged-dragging).

Add a handler for `onRowDragMove`, and use the  `node` and `overIndex` or `overNode` properties of the event to update your local event order state, and pass it to the `AgGridReact` component to re-render.

[Take a look at this example from the docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/row-dragging/#example-simple-unmanaged)